# Duplicate tags for trigonometric functions

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

I recently came across [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981792/sin-function-implementation) (deleted now) tagged with both [sin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sin) and [sine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sine). These tags are not interconnected as I would expect.

The wiki excerpts prove they have the same meaning, each of them mentions the other variant.

> Sin is short for **sine**, mathematical trigonometric function of an angle.
>
> (from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sin/info)

[sin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sin) is used by 271 questions currently.

> Anything related to the mathematical sine function, usually abbreviated as **`sin`**…
>
> (from https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sine/info)

[sine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sine) is used by 251 questions currently (and 6 questions have both tags).

Similarly, there are [cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cos) and [cosine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cosine) used by 142 and 179 questions, respectively (and 3 with both tags).

I suggest making [sin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sin) a synonym for [sine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sine) and [cos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cos) a synonym for [cosine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cosine). The latter ones are the names that can be found in dictionaries, unlike their abbreviations. Moreover, the word *sin* has its own meaning in English, unrelated to trigonometry.

Comment: Moderator note: if this is deemed appropriate by the community, we can simply merge these tags and create a synonym in a single step. **It is not necessary for someone to go through and manually retag them all.** The question here is, looking at the questions with the [[tag:sin]] and [[tag:cos]] tags, are they ready for an immediate merge into [[tag:sine]] and [[tag:cosine]], respectively, or are there some that need to be individually retagged first?

Comment: Are these tags necessary at all? In my opinion they do not add any valuable information. Can you be an expert in sine or cosine?

Comment: As well as the[sin]+[sine] and [cos]+[cosine] pairs, there are also 87 [sin]+[cos] and 25 [sine]+[cosine] pairs, and even 6 [sin]+[cosine] and 4 [sine]+[cos].  Not technically wrong, but a bit surprising.  I can't see that an automatic clean up to just [sine] and [cosine] would cause major problems as long as the fact that the edit might need to drop rather than rename the tag is handled.  That's if they are kept at all.  It's interesting that neither [tan] nor [tangent] is a valid tag at the moment.

Comment: Shouldn't it all just be [tag:trigonometry]? We have a tag for that and it has 1500 questions...

Comment: Merging them all into [[tag:trigonometry]] would also be an option, and I think one worth considering. Hard to see why we would need the granularity of *specific* trigonometric functions, and as Jonathan points out, many questions already use multiple trig-function tags. This would be just as easy to do, so...thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mentioned tags have been merged to [trigonometry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trigonometry) as of now. Thanks to everyone involved!